# how to return multple docs from mongoose and display in html

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Everytime I try to return multiple documents in a collection and display them using ejs engine on my web page I get an error that 'date' property cannot be read but I saw in my console log that it returned an array of results that were consistant with my query.  How do I return these results and post all of the results onto the webpage using ejs?  I tried using a for loop on the array of results returned but it did not work. any suggestions?
Here is part of my server code.

```
   app.get('/userprofile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

        async.parallel([

            function(callback) {
                UserInfo.findOne({'infom.username' : req.user.local.username}, function(err,userinfo){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;

                    callback(null, userinfo);
                })
            },

            function(callback) {
                UserPost.find({'post.username' : req.user.local.username}, function(err, userpost) {
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    console.log(userpost);
                    callback(null, userpost);
                })
            }
            ],
            function(err, results){
                if(err)
                    throw err;

                var userinfo = results[0];
                var userpost = results[1];

                res.render('userprofile', {
                    userinfo : userinfo,
                    userpost : userpost,
                    user : req.user
                })
            })
    })
```

Here is part of my html file.

```
<div id="userpost">
        <% if(userpost!=null) { %>

        <h3><%= user.local.username%></h3><h4><%= userpost.post.date%></h4>
        <h4><%= userpost.post.message%></h4>

        <% } %>
    </div>
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
TypeError: C:\javascript\views\userprofile.ejs:124
    122| <% if(userpost!=null) { %> 
    123| 
 >> 124| <h3><%= user.local.username%></h3><h4><%= userpost.post.date%></h4> 
    125| <h4><%= userpost.post.message%></h4> 
    126| 
    127| <% } %> 

Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\javascript\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:455:12), <anonymous>:45:41)
    at C:\javascript\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:14
```

User Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    post    :   {   
                username : String,
                message : String,
                date : Date
    }
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('UserPost', postSchema);
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet of the error you are getting?
Also, what does the userpost schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method on a Mongoose model will return an empty array if there is no error and there are no results round for a particular query.
In EJS (and JavaScript in general), an empty array does not equal null (i.e. `[] != null`).

This is most likely causing the conditional in your ejs/html to pass (`<% if(userpost!=null) { %>`). However, an empty array obviously doesn't have the properties of your UserPost model, thus `userpost.post` will be undefined.

There are several ways to prevent this from happening. Either add further conditionals in your EJS file, or preferably check for an 'empty' result in your server code prior to rendering.